# Windows Server 2008 R2 slows internet speed

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet, performance

I just installed Windows Server 2008 R2 as my main file server on my home network.  I've noticed that often times when I start my day my internet connection speed is slow.  I'll go to [Speakeasy speed test](http://www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/) and it'll be at about 25% of its normal speed.  When I restart my Server 2008 machine it increases back to normal.  It will stay normal until Server 2008 has been running for a while.  Any ideas?

Edit: I had installed Collabnet Subversion within the past week which installs/sets up some other stuff for web access, I just uninstalled it.  I'll report back tomorrow if that fixed my problem.

Comment: Can you tell us about your network layout?  Do you have a router or is the Win2008 box your gateway?

Comment: i have a router so the 2k8 box is not a gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Windows Server Update Services on it? If you are then it's probably downloading a large amount of updates for clients.

Comment: I checked roles and it's not installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check network utilization on the server (via Task Manager) when this problem happens; if it really is high, then you can examine which process has open network connections (and to where) with the command NETSTAT -NAO.

Comment: I looked at the Networking tab on task manager and it looks normal.  I restarted, internet speed increased and task manager looks the same.  Obviously it's consuming bandwidth for some reason...I'll keep playing around with network monitoring tools and see what i can find

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to help you see what's going on on-the-wire.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a virus? 2008 R2 hasn't been released yet, so you're either using a Release Candidate, or a non-official version you downloaded. If the latter, it could be pre-infected with a virus or worm.

The only ways a separate box can affect your Internet download speed is either a) it is downloading stuff itself, or b) it is flooding your local network.

Pre-emptive anti-nit-pick: the earliest Windows 2008 R2 is available in full production version is late August, they will release a demo version mid August.